# Is there a way to make a specific cell in Shiny datatable editable after clicking an actionbutton on that cell's row?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, action-button

My this question is based on my previous post, which is this: [R shiny app row actionbutton not generating with new row addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73143493/r-shiny-app-row-actionbutton-not-generating-with-new-row-addition)

so what I am trying to do is if I click on "Reward" on row 2 for Alice, I would be able to change her Motivation Cell value, if I don't click on it, then I can't change any values and this goes for all the rows. Is that possible?

I tried with restricting editable in DT but that doesn't help in making the code restrictive to the actionbutton click corresponding to the cell.

Thank you in advance! Greatly appreciate the help!